# How to extend styled component without passing props to underlying DOM element?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a styled component that is extending a third-party component:

```
import Resizable from 're-resizable';
...
const ResizableSC = styled(Resizable)``;
export const StyledPaneContainer = ResizableSC.extend`
    flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.someProp}px;
`;


const PaneContainer = ({ children, someProp }) => (
    <StyledPaneContainer
        someProp={someProp}
    >
        {children}
    </StyledPaneContainer>
);

export default PaneContainer;
```

This resulted in the following error in the browser console:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `someProp` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `someProp` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element

So, I changed the prop to have a `data-*` attribute name:

```
import Resizable from 're-resizable';
...
const ResizableSC = styled(Resizable)``;
export const StyledPaneContainer = ResizableSC.extend`
    flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props['data-s']}px;
`;


const PaneContainer = ({ children, someProp }) => (
    <StyledPaneContainer
        data-s={someProp}
    >
        {children}
    </StyledPaneContainer>
);

export default PaneContainer;
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a native way to use props in the styled component without them being passed down to the DOM element (?)

Answer (score 93):

### 2020 UPDATE: Use transient props

With the [release 5.1.0](https://styled-components.com/releases#v5.1.0) you can use [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props). This way you do not need an extra wrapper i.e. unnecessary code is reduced:

> Transient props are a new pattern to pass props that are explicitly consumed only by styled components and are not meant to be passed down to deeper component layers. Here's how you use them:

```
const Comp = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.$fg || 'black'};
`;

render(<Comp $fg="red">I'm red!</Comp>);
```

> Note the dollar sign ($) prefix on the prop; this marks it as transient and styled-components knows not to add it to the rendered DOM element or pass it further down the component hierarchy.

### The new answer should be:

styled component:

```
const ResizableSC = styled(Resizable)``;
export const StyledPaneContainer = ResizableSC.extend`
    flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.$someProp}px;
`;
```

parent component:

```
const PaneContainer = ({ children, someProp }) => (
    <StyledPaneContainer
        $someProp={someProp}  // '$' signals the transient prop        
    >
        {children}
    </StyledPaneContainer>
);
```

Comment: I really wish the styled-components documentation had been updated to include this

Comment: Updated the documentation in answer - https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

Comment: This should be the accepte answer.

Answer (score 49):

As suggested by [vdanchenkov](https://github.com/vdanchenkov) on [this styled-components github issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/135) you can destructure the props and only pass the relevant ones to `Resizable`

```
const ResizableSC = styled(({ someProp, ...rest }) => <Resizable {...rest} />)`
    flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.someProp}px;
`;
```

Comment: you'll have to import react into the file where this is written to make this work

Comment: I believe this will also kill any `as="foo"` type props too

Answer (score 12):

For those (like me) that landed here because of an issue with SC and react-router's `Link`.

This is basically the same answer as @tskjetne, but with JS syntax style.

```
const StyledLink = styled(({ isCurrent, ...rest }) => <Link {...rest} />)(
  ({ isCurrent }) => ({
    borderBottomColor: isCurrent ? 'green' : 'transparent',
  }),
)
```

Comment: How didn't I think of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: If we have to use it like this, styled-components doesn't make that much sense anymore. It could have been a nice `styled(Link)```...``but not.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 5.1, you can use [`shouldForwardProp`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop) configuration property:

> This is a more dynamic, granular filtering mechanism than transient props. It's handy in situations where multiple higher-order components are being composed together and happen to share the same prop name. `shouldForwardProp` works much like the predicate callback of `Array.filter`. A prop that fails the test isn't passed down to underlying components, just like a transient prop.
>
> Keep in mind that, as in this example, other chainable methods should always be executed after `.withConfig`.

I find it much cleaner than [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props), because you don't have to rename a property, and you become explicit about your intentions:

```js
const ResizableSC = styled(Resizable).withConfig({
  // Filter out the props to not be shown in DOM.
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
    prop !== 'someProp'
    && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
})`
  flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.someProp}px;
`;
```

This is especially handy if you are using TypeScript and sharing the same props type both in your main component and the corresponding styled component:

```js
import { HTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Props type.
type CaptionProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement> & {
  size: number,
};

// Main component.
export const CaptionStyles = styled('p').withConfig<CaptionProps>({
  // Filter out the props to not be shown in DOM.
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) => (
    prop !== 'size'
    && defaultValidatorFn(prop)
  ),
})`
  flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.size}px;
`;

// Corresponding styled component.
export function Caption({ size }: CaptionProps) {
  return (
    <CaptionStyles size={size} />
  );
}
```

[`shouldForwardProp` API reference](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop)

Answer (score -1):

You can try with **defaultProps**:

```
import Resizable from 're-resizable';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...
const ResizableSC = styled(Resizable)``;
export const StyledPaneContainer = ResizableSC.extend`
    flex: 0 0 ${(props) => props.someProp}px;
`;

StyledPaneContainer.defaultProps = { someProp: 1 }

const PaneContainer = ({ children }) => (
    <StyledPaneContainer>
        {children}
    </StyledPaneContainer>
);

export default PaneContainer;
```

We can also pass props using '**attrs**'. This helps in attaching additional props (Example taken from styled components official doc):

```
const Input = styled.input.attrs({
  // we can define static props
  type: 'password',

  // or we can define dynamic ones
  margin: props => props.size || '1em',
  padding: props => props.size || '1em'
})`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* here we use the dynamically computed props */
  margin: ${props => props.margin};
  padding: ${props => props.padding};
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Input placeholder="A small text input" size="1em" />
    <br />
    <Input placeholder="A bigger text input" size="2em" />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Could you explain this answer?

Comment: You can pass default props to the component StyledPaneContainer using defaultProps. Did you try this out?

Comment: No, I wanted to understand why `defaultProps` was suggested if the value of `someProp` needs to be dynamic (?)

Comment: In that we can try with 'attrs'. Updating my answer. Please check, let me know your thoughts on the same.

Comment: Unfortunately `attrs` passes all props through to the DOM, so it doesn't prevent React's invalid props warning unless you're only using prop names that also happen to be valid HTML attributes. I hope styled-components improves its API in the future to better support this use case. In the meantime @tskjetne's answer is a viable workaround for most cases.