# styled-components: Extend existing component with additional prop for styling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm using styled-components to override styling from an existing component, in this case `ToggleButton` from material ui. However I want my new component to have one additional property (`hasMargin`) that controls the style:

```
import {ToggleButton} from "@material-ui/lab";
import styled, {css} from "styled-components";

const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)<{ hasMargin?: boolean }>`
  && {
    color: red;

    ${props => props.hasMargin &&
      css`
          margin: 10px;
      `}
   }
`;
```

My intention is that `StyledToggleButton` behaves exactly like `ToggleButton` but has red color and can be called with an additional property `hasMargin` to turn on the margin css. I want to call it like this:

```
    <StyledToggleButton
      value={""} // ToggleButton prop
      size={"small"} // ToggleButton prop
      hasMargin={true} // My prop from StyledToggleButton
    >
      click
    </StyledToggleButton>
```

But if I do it like this, in the browser console I get:

`` Warning: React does not recognize the `hasMargin` prop on a DOM element. ``

This is because `StyledToggleButton` seems to also pass `hasMargin` further to `ToggleButton` and `ToggleButton` of course can't and shouldn't deal with that (passing it down to the DOM element where it makes no sense). What is the best way to rewrite my code, so `hasMargin` is only processed by `StyledToggleButton`?

I've made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-villani-bteeq?file=/src/App.tsx) to illustrate the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend styled component without passing props to underlying DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834251/how-to-extend-styled-component-without-passing-props-to-underlying-dom-element)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is exactly what [transient props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props) are for.

All you need to do is prefix the prop with a `$` and `styled-components` won't pass the prop to the underlying DOM element.

```
// Note the $ prefix in the prop name             
const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)<{ $hasMargin?: boolean }>`
  && {
    color: red;

    // Just use the prop as normal
    ${(props) =>
      props.$hasMargin &&
      css`
        margin: 10px;
      `}
  }
`;

<StyledToggleButton
  value={""}
  size={"small"}
  {/* Assign the prop as normal */}
  $hasMargin={true}
>
  click
</StyledToggleButton>;
```

Here's your [updated Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-margulis-i87mc) with that error gone.

Comment: Great, thank you! This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping the ToggleButton with span and applying styles from there?

```
const StyledToggleButton = styled.span<{ hasMargin?: boolean }>`
  margin: ${props => props.hasMargin && '50px'};
  
  button {
    color: red !important;
  }  
`

interface MyButtonProps extends ToggleButtonProps {
  hasMargin?: boolean;
}

function MyButton(props: MyButtonProps) {
  const { hasMargin, ...toggleButtonProps } = props;

  return (
    <StyledToggleButton hasMargin={hasMargin} >
      <ToggleButton {...toggleButtonProps}>
      {props.children}
      </ToggleButton>
    </StyledToggleButton>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton value={""}>click</MyButton>

      <MyButton value={""} size={"small"} hasMargin={true}>
        click
      </MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for this simple example that would be an option. But I really want to know how I can override the ToggleButton directly. In my real project is is far more than only margin